# Percentage calculation always returns me 0

Tags: c#

I'm calculating the percentage to add in a datagrid, but when I report the data it always returns me 0, what am I doing wrong?

if I have the following case: the variable quantidadeInstalada has the value of 10 and the goal has 20 the concluido would have to return me 50 but it returns me 0

```
 private void AdicionarPessoa()
 {
     string Valida = ValidaPessoa();
     if (Valida.Equals(""))
     {
         double concluido=0, falta=0;
         int quantidadeInstalada = Convert.ToInt32(ttbQuantidade.Text);
         int meta = Convert.ToInt32(ttbMetaPessoa.Text);

         concluido = (quantidadeInstalada/meta)*100;
         falta = 100-concluido;

         MessageBox.Show(concluido.Text);
     }
     else
         MessageBox.Show(Valida);
 }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably due to the precision of the `int`. Use a `decimal` or `double` instead.

When we use an integer, we lose precision.

```
Console.WriteLine(100 / 17); // 5
Console.WriteLine(100 / 17m); // 5.8823529411764705882352941176     
Console.WriteLine(100 / 17d); // 5.88235294117647
Console.WriteLine(100 / 17f); // 5.882353
```

Since integers always round down, `0.99` as an integer is `0`.

---

Note that for precision, the types of the inputs matters.

```
double output = input1 * input2;
```

For example:

```
double outputA = 9 / 10;
Console.WriteLine(outputA); // 0

double outputB = 9 / 10d;
Console.WriteLine(outputB); // 0.9

double outputC = 9d / 10;
Console.WriteLine(outputC); // 0.9
```

[Here is a Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s5HISa)

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot, but why does it happen? the right one would not only be the end result be of the decimal type or double?

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're doing integer division. You can fix it by casting one of the variables to a `double` like this:

```
concluido = ((double)quantidadeInstalada/meta)*100;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're dividing int by int (as in "quantidadeInstalada/meta"), you'll get an int. Either use a fractional type (e.g. decimal, double) from the very beginning, as [Shaun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108891/shaun-luttin) suggested, or (if the integral types have to stay), cast the values to a fractional type in the division expression (as [itsme86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1141432/itsme86) shown).